# How to perform integration testing in Netty 4

Tags: netty, netty4

In [Netty in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/netty-in-action), I read about [EmbeddedChannel](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/embedded/EmbeddedChannel.html) which can be used for unit testing.

My use case now goes beyond unit testing, and more of integration testing. I want to be able to start the server and then, and within the test, configure/modify the channel handlers.

How is such an integration test setup possible in Netty 4?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are asking about here... Sure you can just start a Netty server as normal by bootstrap it and then modify the pipeline on the fly by using `channel.pipeline()...` .